# Quickly browse your Steam games through webpage

Tags: steam

Is there an easy way to quickly access all my games when visiting Steam through [their webpage](https://store.steampowered.com/)? Without Steam client actually being installed on particular machine. Just the web browser and me?

Let's say that I want to a quick overview of it on my friend's computer. I can login (if necessary) to Steam through website, but I don't want to actually install Steam client on that particular machine.

So far I managed to figure out that following link should do the trick:

```
https://steamcommunity.com/id/<user_name>/games/?tab=all
```

But it seems it isn't easy to locate it and it must be clicked-out, which is a bit annoying.

Is there any element (be it: menu item, some link, icon, etc.) that is available on every page of [store.steampowered.com](https://store.steampowered.com/) website (after I login, of course) that would give me a quick access to the above link or by any other mean -- to a complete list of all games that I own?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any element (be it: menu item, some link, icon, etc.) that is available on every page of store.steampowered.com website

Yes:

[image: Games link]

Which brings you to your games page, from which you can simply click the "all" tab

Comment: Oh, I wouldn't have asked if that had been so obvious! :) I _don't have_ the two items depicted in your image, i.e. _Games_ and _Wishlists_. My so called user menu contains (from top): _Activity_, _Profile_, _Friends_, _Groups_, _Content_, _Badges_ and _Inventory_. See for yourself [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV0Sd.jpg). The link given in question for [my user](https://steamcommunity.com/id/the_trejder/games/?tab=all) lists [0 games](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRUmu.jpg) for non-logged in users, while it shows me [all my 3 games](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1rJr.jpg) when I am logged in.

Comment: Could the above be because of the fact that I haven't been playing for a longer time (about 6+ months or more)? Or could the reason be different? Anyway, can you update your answer to cover the situation, why I don't see what I am supposed to see (according to your answer and screenshot)? Also, if you could add to your answer the actual URL that is opened when you click depicted `Games` item in user menu, so I can verify this on my Steam account. This way, I think, we can craft a more comprehensive answer here. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: @trejder: Try clicking 'profile', then clicking 'games' on the right

Comment: When I click "Profile" in my user menu, I see my profile, but I see nothing titled "Games" to the right. In addition, it keeps saying everywhere that I am offline and that I have logged in last time 120+ days ago even though I have logged-in seconds ago in fact. I start to believe that page does not show my games anywhere (and no links as well), because I have Steam client uninstalled on all my computers. I think you have to have it installed on at least one PC to see what you have shown in your screenshot. But, I may be wrong.